# Division Algorithm Existence by Well Ordering Principle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is what I have so far as a proof for the existence of $q$ and $r$ for $n=mq+r$ in the division algorithm. Is there anything wrong? Can I fix $l$ as I do in the second paragraph of my proof?

Also, I am aware that this is a rather specific case in that it fails to consider all of $\Bbb Z$ or when $r=0$. It is deliberately written this way.

Finally, please accept my apologies for any wonky presentation as I'm a bit new to this.

> **Theorem** If $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $m < n$ and if $m$ does not divide $n$, then there are natural numbers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=mq+r$.
>
> **Proof** Fix $m$ and $n$. Define $S = \{s \in \Bbb N : (s+1)m>n\}$. $S$ is non-empty because $s \in \Bbb N$ can be chosen as large as needed such that $(s+1)m>n$. Since $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$, $S$ has a least element $l$ such that $(l+1)m>n$ by the Well Ordering Principle. This implies that $lm<n$ because if $lm \ge n$, $l$ is not the least element of $S$.
>
> Fix $l$. Since $l$ is the least element of $S$ and $m$ does not divide $n$, there exists  $t \in \Bbb N$ such that $t=n-lm \gt 0$. Rearranging the expression, we can see that $n=ml+t$. If we compare this to the theorem, we also see that $q=l$ and $r=t$.
>
> Thus, if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $m \lt n$ and if $m$ does not divide $n$, then there are natural numbers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=mq+r$. $\Box$

Comment: What if we take $q=1$ and $r=n-m$?

Comment: @JohnGriffin Then $r$ is still positive and the algorithm still works. I get you're trying to point out a flaw but it all seems sound still if $q=1$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin. What is missing in the proof is that if $l=\min S$ then $lm\leq n$ by def'n of $S$ and by def'n of $l$, and this  implies $lm<n$, because $lm=n\implies m|n$,, contrary to the hypothesis.

Comment: @JohnGriffin. An important point is that $r<m$, which should be stated as part of the Theorem.  As written, we could let $q=1$ and $r=n-m.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Just to be clear, I wanted to point out that I never said that $lm=n$. We're saying from the get go that $m$ doesn't divide $n$. As I said, this proof is only for the special case that $m$ doesn't divide $n$. I get that $r \lt m$ should be in the theorem so it isn't so weak, but for the purposes of the theorem **stated**, this is solid... Yes?

Comment: @OliverOz The proof you provided seems okay (except I would omit the sentence "Fix $\ell$".) However, simply letting $q=1$ and $r=n-m$ provides a much simpler proof to this weaker version of the division algorithm.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Yeah, I was thinking about that because it seems kind of pointless to fix $l$ when $m$ and $n$ are both already fixed... It's a bit pointless. With that last bit, I'm not sure why I could say $q=1$, wouldn't that only show it works for that specific case? How does that prove it for all $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @OliverOz The reason the sentence "Fix $\ell$." should be removed is because you have already fixed $\ell$ in the paragraph above as the least element of $S$. For the second question, note that you are trying to show that for any $n,m$ with the given conditions, there exists natural numbers $q,r$ such that $n=mq+r$. Given such an $n,m$, taking $q=1$ and $r=n-m$ yields two natural numbers with the desired property. Thus it proves the statement for all naturals $m,n$ satisfying the hypothesis.